# AngularJS or ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, extjs

I want to build a web application which provide a some kind of analysis service.
I hope to build the back-end with PHP or JavaEE which supports RESTful API.
For front-end I want some framework to use light, easy for development/learn, ... etc.
I heard about AngularJS or ExtJS. which is better?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to stack. I'm afraid your question is too opinion based, have you looked around the web to do some research into both frameworks?

Comment: John if your service based on analytic so extjs provide most power full tool .Other wise you can select on your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends with your expectations. But seems more suitable choice for you AngularJS.
May be you should do some research around..

[This](http://www.sagivfrankel.com/2013/10/26/angularjs-vs-extjs-through-my-experience/) is bit fare comparison.
But Even in that article something are seems wrong. (Ex:- he said angular is harder to understand, for me it's not). So, you'll be finding more of opinion based answers.
Best thing is after doing some reading try to use both of them, then you decide what to use.

Anyway, AngularJS will be better if you are looking for opensource/free framework.